# rewriting urls like facebook profile using Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have an index function with a parameter user_id in controller profile.php and im having a hard time on how to rewrite in htaccess my url. www.domainname/profile/(user_id) into www./domainname/username.

I will be really grateful for replies. Thanks :)

Comment: You can do it using routes in CI.

Comment: You can use routes as Nish said but you will need to change your profile method to take the username as an input (not the user id). So your queries will need changing as well.